# Android recyclerview animation not working

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview, android-animation, android-recyclerview

I want to use a RecyclerView animation like the ones that can be found on the google newsstand app, where the cards animate up or down depending on the scroll direction.

I have the following code right now:

```
public class NewsRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsRVAdapter.NewsViewHolder> {

    private final List<NewsItems> item;
    private int lastPosition = -1;

    public static class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        final TextView title;
        final TextView message;
        final LinearLayout container;

        NewsViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            container = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.news_container);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_list_title);
            message = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_list_message);
        }
    }

    public NewsRVAdapter(List<NewsItems> persons){
        this.item = persons;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_news, viewGroup, false);
        return new NewsViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NewsViewHolder NewsViewHolder, int position) {
        NewsViewHolder.title.setText(item.get(position).getTitle());
        NewsViewHolder.message.setText(Html.fromHtml(item.get(position).getMessage()), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.context, (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top);
        NewsViewHolder.container.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return item.size();
    }
}
```

down_from_top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="400" />
</set>
```

up_from_bottom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="400" />
</set>
```

The problem I have is that some items just don't animate and the other cards that animate just animate right above the ones that don't and it all looks like crap. 
I noticed it is always the 2nd last card when scrolling down and up that doesn't animate. How can I fix that? 
Also when I leave the activity and go back to it, the cards do't animate, but just jump.

Comment: Does really nobody know a solution to this?

Comment: You mean that your animation is not working properly?

Comment: @SurenderKumar It does work but not fully. The 2nd last item always stays there without animating, so the 1st and 3rd card slide over it and it doesn't look nice

Comment: you can use only one animation...for proper animation. If you want to use both then check your position that you are using as lastposition.

Comment: @SurenderKumar I am doing that??

Comment: Remove this code - (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top and use one animation here like  -R.anim.up_from_bottom and try again.

Comment: But then the animation only shows when I scroll down, I want it to also show when I scroll up!